# Use faker to generate java last names but required letters only

Tags: java, expression, faker

It is required to use some names generator in our tests, so we've used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
</dependency>

Faker faker = new Faker();
String firstName = faker.name().firstName();
String lastName = faker.name().lastName();
```

works pretty clear. But time to time we are failed because of `'` generated in last name for example `O'Keefe`, `D'Amore`. The requirement is do not use `'` there. Trying to fix it I've used some expressions before using `faker` instance like next one:

```
faker.expression("[A-Za-z]+");
```

...and others (`#{regexify '(A-Za-z)'}`, `#{regexify '[A-Za-z]+'}` ...), but it doesn't help. (I can detect `'` in last names anyway.)

Is any ideas how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faker has bunch of yml files that have most popular names/lastnames etc. There are bunch of locales supported. The way you can solve your problem is to provide custom file for custom locale.

`Faker faker = new Faker(new Locale("en","TEST"));`

Custom file example (`en-TEST.yml`):

```
en-TEST:
  faker:
    name:
      name:
        - "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
      first_name: [
                    Adedayo
                  ]
      last_name: [
                    Tella
                  ]
```

So you can copy `last_name` values from default file ( `en` locale ) and remove everything that you don't like. Faker will pick up custom file and use it for random generation.

p.s.
As an option you can just go through existing files and just find one without bad lastnames ( `en-NG` seems to be fine for your needs ). However it's not guaranteed that new versions of faker will retain same values.

Answer (score 1):

Can use the `replaceAll` utilizing expression `[^A-Za-z]` to only allow alpha characters:

```
Faker faker = new Faker();
String firstName = faker.name().firstName();
String lastName = faker.name().lastName().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
```

Comment: I think this is workaround that we could avoid of using in case `faker` configured correctly.